# Search in Google and click the link to a particular website

Tags: javascript

I need help regarding this.

1. JavaScript to search a particular keyword in Google.
2. look for a particular website in the result generated.
3. if found click on it.
4. if not found go to the next page and repeat.

I did not get any particular solution to this - hence looking for help from you ALL.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: You cannot use JavaScript in a web page to do what you want. You can possibly spider google using a server server side script or userscript (grease monkey)

Comment: Thanks. I will look.